# Calculus - Find the Critical Values and the Concavity of a Function

Tags: calculus

$f(x) = x^{1/3}(x+1)^{2/3}$

I calculated the critical values as $-1$ only, webwork told me I was wrong. Any advice?

Comment: is it $x^{1/3}(x+1)^{2/3}$?

Comment: Yes it is, im not sure how to format it correctly, ill copy yours! Thanks

Comment: For which values is this function defined? It is complex valued on (-1,0).

Comment: Just a thought: $f'(x) = \frac{1}{3}x^{-\frac{2}{3}}(x+1)^{\frac{2}{3}} + \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{1}{3}}(x+1)^{\frac{-1}{3}}$, if $x=-1$ then the second term is undermined because we are dividing by $0$?

Comment: The correct result is $x=-1/3$. I am writing up an answer presently, but I am wondering what the intended domain of this function is.

Comment: I was also going to ask that, as $x=\frac{-1}{3}$ assumes complex roots. I feel like this question probably doesn't intend that... Although I would like to see how you obtained that solution regardless, if that matters to you.

Comment: @Antonios-AlexandrosRobotis - A domain was not specified.

Comment: I posted my answer- I'm somewhat hesitant about it. So, let me know if/when you find some errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Differentiate to find:
$$ f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}(x+1)^{2/3}+\frac{2}{3}x^{1/3}(x+1)^{-1/3}.$$
Set this equation equal to zero to find 
$$ 0=\frac{1}{3}x^{-2/3}(x+1)^{2/3}+\frac{2}{3}x^{1/3}(x+1)^{-1/3}\implies 0=x^{-2/3}(x+1)^{2/3}+2x^{1/3}(x+1)^{-1/3}.$$
Now, suppose $x\ne0,-1$ and multiply by $x^{2/3}$ to find
$$ 0=(x+1)^{2/3}+2x(x+1)^{-1/3}.$$
Next multiply by $(x+1)^{1/3}$ for the form
$$0=(x+1)+2x. $$
Rearranging we can see 
$$ 3x=-1\implies x=\frac{-1}{3}.$$
There is a critical point at $\frac{-1}{3}$. Now it remains to verify the concavity of the function. To do this, we must differentiate again.
$$ f''(x)=\frac{-2}{9}x^{-5/3}(x+1)^{2/3}+\frac{2}{9}x^{-2/3}(x+1)^{-1/3}+\frac{2}{9}x^{-2/3}(x+1)^{-1/3}+\frac{-2}{9}x^{1/3}(x+1)^{-4/3}.$$
Arbitrarily set $x=-2$. We can see by evaluation that $f''(-2)$ is negative, and so it should be concave down. The same applies for $x=1, f(x)$ is also concave down at $x=1.$ The only place concavity could change would be a critical point, which is only at $x=\frac{-1}{3}$, so we know that the function is globally concave down.

Comment: Going to email my prof about it, see if that seems to be correct, It looks correct to me. Thanks man

Comment: Be sure to ask about the domain, because there is definitely some ambiguity in the fact that this function is not $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ as stated.